# Como bloquear a 'scrollbar' quando estiver navegado em um aparelho desktop?

Tags: css

Estou utilizando Bootstrap 4. Como bloquear a '*scrollbar*' (a barra lateral de rolagem) quando estiver navegado em um aparelho *desktop*?

Comment: Vc quer saber se está num "desktop" de verdade ou saber pela resolução da tela? Pela resolução da tela é difícil porque existem tablets e smartphones de alta resolução.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar *[media-queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)* para remover o scrollbar. No exemplo abaixo, filtramos o *media type* `screen` e a largura `min-width` para caracterizar um *Desktop*.

Isso nos permite remover o scroll considerando apenas para as características selecionadas.

```
    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
      html {
             overflow: hidden;
           }
    }
```